# Python: Function to count an output of another function

Tags: python

I'm trying to learn Python and I have an excercise in which I have a function which generates a random number and I have to create another function to count how many times a number appears in that output after calling the random generator like a 1000 times.
This is what i have done so far:

```
from random import *

def gerador_aleatorio():
    return randint(0, 10)

def histograma():
    num = {range(gerador_aleatorio())}
    for n in range(gerador_aleatorio()):
        return num
    hist = {}
    for i in num: 
        hist[i] = hist[i] + 1
    return hist
```

But the output is not what i whant. It appears like this:

=> histograma()

=> {range(0, 7)}

When i am looking for something like this:

0 - 6

1 - 894

2 - 92

3 - 82

4 - 53

5 - 89

6 - 85

7 - 28

8 - 51

9 - 81

10 - 92

I'm failing to "connect" the output of the first function with the second one and i'm not seeing how to do it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be careful when importing with * as you may have some name collision, it's better to just import the method and call it as method.func_name() **

```
import random

def gerador_aleatorio():
    return random.randint(0, 10)

def histograma():
    hist = {}

    for count in range(int(input('Enter amount of rand nums: '))):
        num = gerador_aleatorio()
        hist.setdefault(num, 0)
        hist[num] += 1

    for number in hist: 
        print(str(number) + ': ' + str(hist[number]))

histograma()
```

You can store all the numbers in a dictionary, and count them each time it occurs.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on importing with *. This works perfectly, i will compare with with my code to learn what i did wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help. You might also want to look into try/except and catch that input into a variable to remove non-numeric answers.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply construct the histogram using `collections.Counter()` as :

```
import collections

def histograms():
    return  collections.Counter(gerador_aleatorio() for i in xrange(1000))

>>> histograms()
>>> {3: 99, 10: 99, 0: 97, 9: 95, 1: 88, 2: 88, 5: 88, 8: 88, 7: 87, 4: 86, 6: 85}
```

What the above snippet is doing, getting the random `1000` values by calling the random number generator function, and the creating a histogram of the `1000` values returned by the function, another simpler implementation of the same function can be seen as:

```
def histograms():
    a = []
    for i in xrange(1000):
        a.append(gerador_aleatorio())
    return collections.Counter(a)
```

In which we store the all the 1000 random numbers in a list and then create a histogram from the given list.

Comment: Could also make gerador_aleatorio() to `yield` instead of `return` :)

Comment: yeah But I mainly focused on implementing the `histogram()` function which was not working properly, rather than adding more complexity to already working snippet.

Comment: Thanks! I did not learn the collections yet :) But this will be very helpful.